# .NET Desktop Application (Service) 3-tier application

Tags: c#, .net, desktop-application, 3-tier

I have just started to design a .NET library that is going to be used by either an application or a service (but this should not matter with 3-tier architecture?) and I'm struggling to find a proper separation of concerns and at the same time link DAL with BL in a proper way.

I was looking for tutorials, etc., but they all point to ASP.NET and Entity Framework, but I'd like to use ADO.NET (DataSets, DataTables) to build a library for desktop application / windows service usage.

Would anyone point me to a right direction by providing any sample/example implenentation or a tutorial/guide??

@EDIT

I was thinking about something like that:

DbManager - abstract class
XDbManager - X being a provider, SQL, etc. deriving from DBManager, being a singleton class (I'd prefer static, but these can't implement interface or derive from classes)
DbConnection - an object returned by DbManager method, containing methods for querying

BaseDbo - abstract class for Database Object
XDbo - X being the name of DBO, using DbManager => DbConnection to query (save, retrieve, retrieve sets, save sets? this is where I'm a bit confused, I need few persistent DataSets to save, update, retrieve data from tables - should they be implemented as Database Objects deriving from DataSets?)

BaseBo - abstract class for Business Object
XBo - business object class to handle and process data, etc.

Saying above I can't find a proper way to "link" both layers.

I also need to make use of SOAP web service in here, should that be implemented on business layer? Or should I introduce a new sub-layer?

Answer (score 0):

If your application is properly designed, using EF or ADO.Net shouldn't matter much: that's the point of the DAL abstraction. I.e. you'll still have a method such as:

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetAllUsers()
{
    ....
}
```

that will returns all of your users. How it's implemented (i.e. Entity Framework or ADO.Net) is not important. The only difference is that your DAL won't be able to return `IQueryable<T>` (i.e. deferred execution won't work, or you'll need another abstraction layer on top of ADO.Net).

Same as for ASP.Net vs Desktop application: this shouldn't vary much either. You should use WCF services instead of ASP.Net MVC controllers. Instead of directly calling the BL from your controller, you would call a method of a WCF generated client proxy.

Everything that you could read about 3-tier application should apply for your use case too.